# Gridview not populating

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have two dropdownlists that are used to generate a gridview that will be edited and updated.  I am lost as to why the gridview will not populate.  I am enclosing the coded that I have.  I have tried hiddenfields, I have parameters right now that seem to be populating correctly, I am just very confused as to why I can't see the gridview.  As a caveat, I need to be able to update the certain columns in the rows either by text box or dropdownlist.  If I change the query on the datasource for the gridview to bring in every row I have in the database, I can see everything and edit and update perfectly.

Here is the code first my aspx then the aspx.cs

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Annos3.aspx.cs" Inherits="SHCAnnotation.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="dlJobName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="JobName" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" 

            style="z-index: 1; left: 25px; top: 50px; position: absolute; bottom: 257px; height: 45px; width: 242px;" 
            onselectedindexchanged="dlJobName_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="JobName" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SRM_MetricConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Name  FROM vw_GridviewSource WHERE (DueDt &gt; sysdatetime()) ORDER BY Name">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvSummary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" AllowSorting = "true" 
         OnRowCancelingEdit = "CancelEdit" OnRowEditing = "EditSummary" OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBound"
        OnRowUpdating = "UpdateSummary" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="AnnotationNumber, Cust, Name, AnnotationDate"
        style="z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 130px; position: absolute; height: 133px; width: 257px" >
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Annotation Number">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblAnno" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnnotationNumber") %>'> </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
           </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Annotation By" HeaderStyle-Width = "250">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblAnnoBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnnotationBy") %>' Width = "150"> </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="450" />
            <ItemStyle Width="450" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

           </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Annotation Type">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblAnnoType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnnotationType") %>' Width = "150"> </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="450px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="450px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
           </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Business Unit" HeaderStyle-Width = "250">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblBU" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Unit") %>' Width = "250" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBU" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Unit") %>' Visible ="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID = "dlBU" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Error Type" HeaderStyle-Width = "250">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblET" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ErrorType") %>' Width = "250" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblET" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ErrorType") %>' Visible ="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID = "dlET" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>    
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Actual Agency Error" HeaderStyle-Width = "250">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblAA" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActualAgencyError") %>' Width = "250" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAA" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActualAgencyError") %>' Visible ="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID = "dlAA" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>      
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "AnnotationComments">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblAnnoComm" runat ="server" Text = '<%# Eval("AnnotationComments") %>' Width = "400"></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "sgk Comments">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID = "lblsgkComm" runat ="server" Text = '<%# Eval("sgkComments") %>' Width = "400"></asp:Label>  
             </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Textbox ID="tbsgkComm" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sgkComments") %>' TextMode = "MultiLine" Columns = "40"  ></asp:Textbox>   
        </EditItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="400px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify" Width="400px" />
           </asp:TemplateField>


    </columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlStage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="Stage" DataTextField="Annotation_Date" 
        DataValueField="Annotation_Date" Height="45px" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 360px; top: 50px; position: absolute" 
        Width="240px" onselectedindexchanged="dlStage_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Stage" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SRM_MetricConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [AnnotationDate] AS Annotation_Date FROM [vw_GridviewSource] WHERE ([Name] = @Name)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dlJobName" Name="Name" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:HiddenField ID = "hfJN" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID = "hfST" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SHCAnnotation
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //hfJN.Value = dlJobName.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                //hfST.Value = dlStage.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                //this.BindDataInit();


            }
        }

        protected void EditSummary(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {            

            gvSummary.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvSummary.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvSummary.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
            {

                DropDownList dlBU = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dlBU");

                string Cust = gvSummary.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values["Cust"].ToString();
                string BUquery = "select distinct Unit from vw_BU where Business ='" + Cust + "'";
                SqlCommand BUcmd = new SqlCommand(BUquery);
                dlBU.DataSource = GetData(BUcmd);
                dlBU.DataTextField = "Unit";
                dlBU.DataValueField = "Unit";
                dlBU.DataBind();
                dlBU.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblBU") as Label).Text).Selected = true;


                DropDownList dlET = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dlET");

                string ETquery = "select distinct ErrorType from ErrorType";
                SqlCommand ETcmd = new SqlCommand(ETquery);
                dlET.DataSource = GetData(ETcmd);
                dlET.DataTextField = "ErrorType";
                dlET.DataValueField = "ErrorType";
                dlET.DataBind();
                dlET.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblET") as Label).Text).Selected = true;

                DropDownList dlAA = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dlAA");

                string AAquery = "select distinct AAA from ActualAgencyError";
                SqlCommand AAcmd = new SqlCommand(AAquery);
                dlAA.DataSource = GetData(AAcmd);
                dlAA.DataTextField = "AAA";
                dlAA.DataValueField = "AAA";
                dlAA.DataBind();
                dlAA.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblAA") as Label).Text).Selected = true;

            }
        }

        protected void UpdateSummary(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            string BU = (gvSummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dlBU") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
            string ET = (gvSummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dlET") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
            string AA = (gvSummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dlAA") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
            string AnnotationNumber = gvSummary.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string sgkComments = (gvSummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("tbsgkComm") as TextBox).Text;
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRM_MetricConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                string query = "update vw_GridviewSource set [BusinessUnit] = @BU, [ErrorType] = @ET, [sgkComments] = @sgk, [ActualAgencyError] = @AA where [AnnotationNumber] = @AnnoNum";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BU", BU);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnnoNum", AnnotationNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ET", ET);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AA", AA);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sgk", sgkComments);



                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                }
            }
        }

        private void BindDataInit()
        {



            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRM_MetricConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select [AnnotationNumber],[AnnotationBy],[AnnotationType],[BusinessUnit] as Unit,[ErrorType],[ActualAgencyError],AnnotationComments,[sgkComments],[ActualAgencyError],Cust,Name,AnnotationDate from vw_GridviewSource" ;

            gvSummary.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            gvSummary.DataBind();
        }




        private void BindData()
        {
            string selectedName = dlJobName.SelectedValue;
            string selectedStage = dlStage.SelectedValue;


            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRM_MetricConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select [AnnotationNumber],[AnnotationBy],[AnnotationType],[BusinessUnit] as Unit,[ErrorType],[ActualAgencyError],AnnotationComments,[sgkComments],[ActualAgencyError],Cust,Name,AnnotationDate from vw_GridviewSource where Name = @p1 and AnnotationDate = @p2";
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",selectedName);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",selectedStage);

            gvSummary.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            gvSummary.DataBind();
        }

        private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            string selectedName = dlJobName.SelectedValue;
            string selectedStage = dlStage.SelectedValue;

            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRM_MetricConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",selectedName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",selectedStage);
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void dlJobName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string JobName = Application["gJob"].ToString();
            BindData();
        }

        protected void dlStage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string stage = Application["gStage"].ToString();
            BindData();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in BindData() and make sure you're passing valid data.  Also, try running the query in SQL Management Studio with the expected values and ensure rows are being returned.

Comment: I did this.  In the private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd) area I call a string selectedName = dlJobName.selectedValue;  I checked that and the selected value is being shown.  I don't think that the datatable is getting populated though.  I did check the query against the database and it should return 20 rows with one selection and 1 row with the other.

Comment: Does your GridView Doesn't loads the first time page is requested?? Also, are you sure the 2 dropdownlists are populated first time the page is loaded??

Comment: I had the gridview populate with the page load event, but did not populate the ddls.  I will try that.  When I populated the gridview originally I populated it with everything that was in the database.  Should I populate it based on the ddls?

Comment: Okay.  The two dropdownlists are postback so I am not sure what I need to do to initialize.  They appear when the page comes up.  What does not happen is the gridview does not come up.  I put the debugger on and found that the selected values for JobName and Stage where not populating at the private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd) function.  They both come back null which is why the gridview does not populate.  How do I initialize the parameters so that they will populate?

Comment: You are already "initializing" the DDLs using the `SQLDataSource` controls.  BindData and GetData are really confusingly set up.  Unify them into one method, get it working, and THEN refactor out into separate methods.  The `SelectedValue`s of each DDL will not be bound until you make a selection, so your GridView will be empty until you select something in each of the DDLs.